# How do I find unique sequences in a vector?

Tags: r

I want to find the unique sequences in my vector. A sequence is a series of identical values. If a sequence repeats, it counts as two sequences, as long as there is another sequence in between. A sequence can have a length of one value.

So that if my function is called findSequences(), it would work like this:

```
my_vector = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b')

find_Sequences(my_vector)

> 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'
```

unique() and distinct() don't do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `rle`.

```
rle(my_vector)$values
#[1] "a" "b" "a" "c" "b"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use comparisons with the preceding item:

```
my_vector[c(TRUE, my_vector[-1] != my_vector[-length(my_vector)])]
```

It should be better than `rle` as it is doing the same with less code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the run length encoding `rle` function:

```
rle(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b'))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 2 1 1 2 1
  values : chr [1:5] "a" "b" "a" "c" "b"
```

The `values` field tells you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table::rleid` and `duplicated` to get unique sequences.

```
my_vector[!duplicated(data.table::rleid(my_vector))] 
#[1] "a" "b" "a" "c" "b"
```